# Is there a way to download the presumably initial bash source bash-0.99?

Tags: bash

I am interested to check which features the oldest public bash source implements.

Is there a way to download this from the net? Google does not help to find anything from before bash-1.14.7.

Comment: Not an answer for 0.99, but incrementally earlier than 1.14.7: https://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/bash/

Comment: Even older : bash 1.05 at http://www.oldlinux.org/Linux.old/bin/old/

Comment: This unfortunately does not help much as this is still from 1994 - 5 years from the expected initial release.

Comment: @user2560053 thank you! this is much closer to what I am looking for, as the youngest file is from Mach 1990 and it includes a Changelog file that goes back to June 1989

Comment: Related: Discussion on origin of shellshock: http://www.openwall.com/lists/oss-security/2014/10/04/2

Answer (score 10):

See this list at [BashFAQ/061](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/061) which provides some information about early version of Bash:

- bash-1.14

  > [1994-06-02](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/gnu.bash.bug/oOfJhX8Es74/H1fYjpvy9toJ)

  Can be found at the archived version of [http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/bash/](http://web.archive.org/web/20030218185304/http://ftp.gnu.org:80/gnu/bash/)
- bash-1.13

  > [1993-09-03](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/gnu.bash.bug/KSGrYVYsxEE/ldpQw6UHd5wJ)

  > Looks like Chet Ramey takes over as maintainer between 1.12 and 1.13.
- bash-1.12

  > [1992-01-26](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/gnu.bash.bug/LqJlezOLPmw/fWEU5dx63swJ)

  You can find [`bash-1.12.lx` file at *oldlinux.org*](http://www.oldlinux.org/Linux.old/bin/old/).
- bash-1.11

  > [1992-01-10](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/gnu.bash.bug/mtiSajVLFWQ/IO7lRZZaXuEJ)

  You can find [`bash-1.11` at *oldlinux.org*](http://www.oldlinux.org/Linux.old/bin/old/bash-1.11/).
- bash-1.10

  > First mention found at [1991-10-07](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/gnu.bash.bug/2JCACpoweVo/VcbTlUED2L8J), so some time before that.
- bash-1.09

  > First mention found at [1991-06-02](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/gnu.bash.bug/r2mPhpzeFA0/uEe2lEymOOAJ).
- bash-1.08

  > [1991-05-22](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/gnu.bash.bug/6IYJUqnlXbo/PtB74jsSdBEJ)
- bash-1.07

  > likely [1991-02-01](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/gnu.bash.bug/IbPT47bVNak/TgM9oOgwDOEJ)
- bash-1.06

  > This is a tough one. There was apparently a "bootleg" version of 1.06, so this requires more digging.
- bash-1.05

  [1990-03-03](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/gnu.bash.bug/sdSJj38zObM/9OJmiMwsEeYJ)

  You can find [`bash-1.05.tar` file at *oldlinux.org*](http://www.oldlinux.org/Linux.old/bin/old/).

  Also find this [copy of origin bash-1.05 at GitHub](https://github.com/Olya-Lap/easy_bash/tree/master/bash-1.05).
- bash-1.04

  > First mention found at [1989-11-07](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/gnu.bash.bug/OEAOMxIgXNM/_0MmMKhwBUoJ)
- bash-1.03

  > [1989-09-02](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/gnu.bash.bug/0BNtldi31-I/0z3R_gKQQ5AJ)

  Also check this [comment from Brian](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!activity/gnu.bash.bug/KsqoeeDF7KgJ/gnu.bash.bug/_LLeCJotr78/jeXcFtFL3PkJ):

  > I didn't post patches right away, which had indeed been my intent.  Since then I have completed a major rewrite of the readline library, and the patches would be meaningless. I tend to be slow to release a piece of software unless I think it is perfect.  Since I know that Bash is not yet perfect, I am slow to release it.  Then, people yell at me to release something, anything, and
  > I rush to get in the last new feature.
- bash-1.02

  > First mention found at [1989-07-09](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/gnu.bash.bug/n6oK8g9ZT_s/ZoiyAtJ0PmgJ).

  You can find [`bash102.taz`](https://web.archive.org/web/20210703075457/http://www.decuslib.com/decus/lt89b2/gnusoftware/bash102.taz) at the archived version of decuslib.com
- bash-1.01

  > [1989-06-23](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/gnu.bash.bug/cDuxRblQx4c/KsqoeeDF7KgJ)
- bash-1.00

  > Hard to search for ...

  As per this Brian's Fox [post](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/gnu.bash.bug/cDuxRblQx4c/KsqoeeDF7KgJ) titled `Bash-1.00.tar.Z` posted on 1989-06-23:

  > I have placed the full source to bash version 1.01 on [prep.ai.mit.edu](http://prep.ai.mit.edu/).

  > There will not be another release of the shell until all of the known
  > and reported bugs are fixed.

  So we can assume that the earliest bash version has been uploaded to the above website. There are also [these mirror sites](http://web.archive.org/web/19990508065749/http://prep.ai.mit.edu:80/order/ftp.html).
- bash-0.99

  > First mention found at [1989-06-11](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/gnu.bash.bug/dliLANZUdwI/X-lY_E-bDRMJ)

However I don't think Bash 0.99 has been anywhere released as per [Brian's comment](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/gnu.bash.bug/cDuxRblQx4c/KsqoeeDF7KgJ):

> The documentation is too incomplete to ship with the shell at this time,
> so I haven't placed it in the release.

You can only check random diff changes by looking at *gnu.bash.bug* forum or [some old posts](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!activity/gnu.bash.bug/KsqoeeDF7KgJ) from the original author ([Brian Fox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brian_Fox_(computer_programmer))).

Comment: There are a few old bash source tarballs at http://www.decuslib.com (Digital Equipment Computer User Society) such as http://www.decuslib.com/decus/lt89b2/gnusoftware/bash102.taz for bash 1.02 the earliest I could find there.